# Difference and resources for Miniscript and Simplicity?

Tags: miniscript, simplicity

I have read about that it is a language for writing Bitcoin Scripts in a structured way, enabling analysis, composition, generic signing and more.

http://bitcoin.sipa.be/miniscript/ is helpful but need more information, examples, libraries etc.

Simplicity is a blockchain programming language designed as an alternative to Bitcoin script and works for Elements.

I need more links or information to try things.

Also can miniscript be used for elements and simplicity be used for bitcoin?

Answer (score 3):

Miniscript is an [encoding](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91565/what-does-bitcoin-policy-language-offer-the-developer-that-miniscript-doesnt-w) of Bitcoin Script. The functionality of Miniscript is a subset of Script so there is nothing you can do with Miniscript that you can't do with Script. Therefore scripts decoded from Miniscript can be used on Bitcoin mainnet today in addition to testnet, regtest, signet and Elements.

In terms of Miniscript resources (in addition to the [one](http://bitcoin.sipa.be/miniscript/) you posted), the following are useful:

- Andrew Poelstra [presentation](https://btctranscripts.com/london-bitcoin-devs/2020-02-04-andrew-poelstra-miniscript/) at London Bitcoin Devs in 2020
- Andrew Poelstra [workshop](https://btctranscripts.com/advancing-bitcoin/2020/2020-02-07-andrew-poelstra-miniscript/) at Advancing Bitcoin 2020
- Blockstream [blog post](https://medium.com/blockstream/miniscript-bitcoin-scripting-3aeff3853620) in September 2019
- [PR](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/16800) to add Miniscript support to Bitcoin Core (C++)
- [PR](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/17975) to add Miniscript support to Bitcoin Core test framework (Python)
- rust-miniscript [library](https://github.com/rust-bitcoin/rust-miniscript) (Rust)

Simplicity, depending on which [jets](https://medium.com/blockstream/simplicity-jets-release-803db10fd589) are enabled, has greater functionality than Script and is a direct alternative to Script rather than just an encoding. In addition:

> Simplicity is a work-in-progress low-level programming language with greater flexibility and expressiveness than Bitcoin Script. It allows you to verify the safety, security and costs of a program.

It is supported on this [test branch](https://github.com/roconnor-blockstream/bitcoin/tree/d4919e23bb48894915a5c4a3ac7277a03739f281) of Bitcoin Core and in [Elements](https://github.com/ElementsProject/elements/tree/235b4b1bb86a41fa73e6a952a8b2696766112a07) but not yet on Bitcoin mainnet.

In terms of Simplicity resources, the following are useful:

- Simplicity [white paper](https://blockstream.com/simplicity.pdf).
- Russell O'Connor [presented](https://btctranscripts.com/blockchain-protocol-analysis-security-engineering/2018/2018-01-25-russell-oconnor-simplicity/) on Simplicity in January 2018.
- Adam Back [presented](https://btctranscripts.com/blockstream-webinars/2020-04-08-adam-back-simplicity/) on Simplicity in April 2020.
- Blockstream posted blog posts in [November 2018](https://blockstream.com/2018/11/28/en-simplicity-github/) and [April 2020](https://medium.com/blockstream/simplicity-jets-release-803db10fd589).
- There is a Bitcoin Optech [topics page](https://bitcoinops.org/en/topics/simplicity/) on Simplicity.

**There is also a Simplicity Discussions [page](https://github.com/BlockstreamResearch/simplicity/discussions) in the Simplicity repo which has a number of interesting Q&A. A more technical question on Simplicity may have already been asked there.**