# What is a Miniscript fragment? And what should I call the underscore letter?

Tags: script, terminology, miniscript

An example [Miniscript](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/91565/what-does-bitcoin-policy-language-offer-the-developer-that-miniscript-doesnt-w) is:

`and_v(or_c(pk(B),or_c(pk(C),v:older(1000))),pk(A))`

(Generated using this Miniscript [site](https://bitcoin.sipa.be/miniscript/)).

What would a fragment be here? What should I call the underscore letter (`_v`)? And the (`v:`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What would a fragment be defined as here?

The functions in Miniscript (e.g. `and_v`, `older(1000)`) are referred to as **fragments**.

> What should I call the underscore letter (`_v`)?

`and_v` is the **fragment** and the `_v` part of it is the **suffix**.

> And the (`v:`)?

The `v:` in `v:older(1000)` is a **wrapper**.

Some [additional definitions](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/24147) may be of interest.

We use the term **valid** for any correctly typed Miniscript. And we use the term **safe** for any **sane** Miniscript, ie one whose satisfaction isn't malleable, which requires a key for any spending path, etc.

Thanks to individuals for answering this on IRC.